# Stability of potassium (fermipressure)

Tags: solid-state-physics, stability, fermi-energy

I have an exercise to calculate the pressure of the fermigas inside a potassium (bcc, $a = 0.525 \,$nm) crystal.
The formula is given with:

$p_0 = \frac{2}{5} \, \frac{N}{V} \, E_f(0)$

The result is $1.9$ GPa, which is quite high. The second part of the task is to argue why the crystal is stable with such a high pressure. 
I only find explanations for neutron stars where you have an equilibrium between gravitation and fermi pressure. But what about a less dense solid state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that there is also an electronic binding energy between the electrons and the potassium nuclei that tries collapse the potassium inwards. The precise density is set by the balance between the fermi pressure and the binding pressure between electrons and nuclei.

The take home message in your exercise, is to me is that you need a very large pressure, on the order of GPa, to compress potassium further.

Comment: Indeed. It is the positive background charge of potassium ions that keep the free electron gas in the "box".